How to set and use a global variable within a content plugin?
It's probably a duplicate.
Anyhow, I am writing a J5 content plugin using onContentPrepare event.
It turns out, that this plugin is called several times before the page is sent to the browser.
I want to execute a short code only during the first call and any subsequent plugin calls to check that flag.
For that reason, I need a flag to be reset before the first call and set on the first code execution. What is the best way to achieve this? Some kind of global variable?

Normally plugins in Joomla are instantiated only once per request. So using a class member variable is the cleanest solution:
use Joomla\CMS\Event\Content\ContentPrepareEvent;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

final class MyPlugin extends CMSPlugin
{
    private bool $flag = false;

    public function onContentPrepare(ContentPrepareEvent $event)
    {
        // Check if flag has been set.
        if (!$this->flag)
        {
            // Set the flag on first run.
            $this->flag = true;

            // Code that will be executed once.
        }

        // Code that will be executed every time.
    }
}

